# How to create column with date type date9. using case when in SAS Enterprise Guide 8.2?

Tags: date, sas, format, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have SAS Enterprise Guide 8.2 and I try to create new column (data type = date) using case when. My code is:

```
proc sql;
select 
col1
, case when (col2 between '01SEP2019'd and '15SEP2019'd) then '01AUG2020'
       when (col2 between '01SEP2019'd and '15SEP2019'd) then '01OCT2020'
  end as col3 format = date9.
from my_table;
quit;
```

Unfortunately, when I run my code I have error: `"ERROR: Character expression requires a character format.`

How can I modify my code so as to have new created col3 as date format in SAS Enterprise Guide 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `d` after the quotes to indicate a date literal.
As posted, your WHEN statements condition are identical though, so only the first one will be applied.

```
proc sql;
select 
col1
, case when (col2 between '01SEP2019'd and '15SEP2019'd) then '01AUG2020'd
       when (col2 between '01SEP2020'd and '15SEP2019'd) then '01OCT2020'd
  end as col3 format = date9.
, input('12344', 8.) as number_col
from my_table;
quit;
```

Comment: Great! It works, I gave best answer, and could you tell me also how can I convert in proc sql in selcet statement string to numerical ? I have for example 12344 in string but I need to select this column as a number ?

Comment: See edits above